ASP.NET Core Swagger with shared contract assembly
Is it possible to reuse types from shared contract assembly?
Currently, on the client side, types are generated from Swagger json. I would like some of them to be reused from shared assembly.
Went through SwaggerGenOptions but found nothing except MapType which does not seem to be what I am looking for.

Hi @mdzieg, can you explain more for your scenario due to I think MapType should be a good way by reading your current description.

@Rena I faced two issues. First was to allow polymorphic deserialization on the client side. I have this almost solved. But still I have to then map types to the types from shared library to have not only data but also the same methods and functionality. I have this service exposed using Refit library and it works great. But when exposing API with Swagger, client generates new types and uses those instead of types from shared library. I do not want custom solution though, but sth that works with generators OOTB. I think this is nor supported but wanted to ask anyways.
